# Error: You have an outdated version of python-requests. Please upgrade

Tags: python, linux, wapiti

My issue is whenever I command `wapiti` it gives me this message:

```
root@ kali: ~#wapiti
Wapiti - 2.3.0(wapiti.sourceforge.net)
Error: You have an outdated version of python - requests.Please upgrade
```

I have upgraded it to the latest version :

```
root@kali:~#  apt-get install python-requests
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-requests is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@kali:~# apt-get install wapiti
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wapiti is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

My kali version is the latest one and I have downloaded Iso and image other version to solve it but I encounter it in each one...I am amd64 if this helps.

Comment: Was `wapiti` from the distro and not clobbered with an update outsite of `apt-get`?  Normally these versions and their dependencies should be coherent w/each other.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a virgin install

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command to upgrade the `requests` module:

```
pip install requests --upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

1- apt-get remove python-requests

2- pip install requests

3- apt-get install python-requests

4- wapiti It will work.

```
Wapiti-2.3.0 (wapiti.sourceforge.net)
Wapiti-2.3.0 - Web application vulnerability scanner 
Usage: python wapiti.py http://server.com/base/url/ [options]
```